# someone posted and it made my computer reboot!

Tags: support

This is annoying - I hate closing all my programs.

Can/Should someone maybe delete the post on SO that just went up and caused my computer to reboot?

[image]

Comment: Link, or it didn't ...

Comment: well it's in the screenshot... i can't go to the page to get the link

Comment: No repro.  You didn't try and execute the posted code, did you?

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. Ever thought about trying Linux?

Comment: I'll put a buck on Avast.  It's a doozy.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Or you could just RANU instead of as admin.

Answer (score 14):

[The post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219358/can-a-file-be-read-and-written-right-back-with-small-changes-without-knowing-its) is about someone attempting to remove virus-laden code from his site, and so he has included samples of this code in his post. It is just included as text; there is no way for this code to run and harm your computer.

Unfortunately, *many* antivirus programs [don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100817/avast-reporting-virus-when-browsing-to-so-question) [realize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112187/stackoverflow-threads-caught-by-anti-virus-programs) this and think it's a threat. This is their bug.

Comment: i figured that's what went down.. my logic is this: alot of people probably use SO from work and use the same Anti Virus as me, and I assume there are others out there with servers running and 4 instances of VS taking up 15 GB ram who will lose a half hour if they bring up that post... I'm just trying to help out...

Comment: @Gabriel: I use a different computer to access the internet than I use for software development.  You should too.

Comment: well, this is the first evidence that makes me tend to agree

Comment: @Gabriel: Not for nothing, but if your antivirus is causing you to lose work due to a false-positive, it's not doing you any favors.  Save early, save often.

Comment: actually it takes me a half an hour to get rebooted and all my workspeces re-opened... not to mention my research-mode browser windows... lol... thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @Gabriel My version of ESET also complained about that page, but didn't require a restart or anything like that...might be related to the fact that you were using Internet Explorer, I suppose.

Comment: @Gabriel: I once had a similar problem at work (long reboots and crappy hardware/software setups, not virus-related).  My team and I ended up keeping a log of lost productivity from the employer-imposed setup (something as simple as a chess clock on the table that you hit every time you're twiddling your thumbs waiting for the workstation).  After a month, each employee's lost productivity in man-hours equaled the cost of a brand new workstation.  Armed with actual evidence and numbers and spreadsheets, management paid more attention.